# always got Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters error

Tags: python, elasticsearch

cant create an easiest mapping from a doc

```
index_name = "index_test"

mapping = {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "age":    { "type": "integer" },
      "email":  { "type": "keyword"  },
      "name":   { "type": "text"  }
    }
  }
}

resp = es.indices.create(index=index_name, body=mapping)
```

version

elastic-transport==8.4.0

elasticsearch==7.17.9

elasticsearch-dsl==7.4.1

got an error

elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {properties={name={type=text}, age={type=integer}, email={type=keyword}}}]')

Answer (score 0):

When updating your mapping you don't need the `mappings` section, just do it like this:

```
mapping =  {
    "properties": {
      "age":    { "type": "integer" },
      "email":  { "type": "keyword"  },
      "name":   { "type": "text"  }
    }
}

index_name = "test_index"

es.indices.put_mapping(index=index_name, body=mapping, doc_type='test')
```

Comment: sry for that


i got en error creating new index like this


es.indices.create(index='index_name', body=mapping)
with the same mapping

Comment: When creating you MUST have the `mappings` section, but when you just update the mapping you don't

Comment: and when i creating a new with mapping section a have an error

Comment: What error do you get?, please update your question with a reproducible example

Comment: You should have added an update, because now my answer is not in synch with your question anymore